# find methods of instance with minimal letters

Tags: android, android-studio

In my previous Android Studio settings I found a way to view all methods of instance with minimal letter and not just with capital letters, I don't find it again .Someone know how to make this ? Thanks.

Comment: please elaborate more

Comment: I want to find the method like this when I am typing : instance.dosomething despite in the object its write : DoSomething(){}